# Foliated vector bundle and basic connection

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, foliations

Let $(M,F)$ be a Riemannian foliation, i.e. there is a metric of $TM$ such that $g$ is bundle-like (locally $g_Q=g_{ij}(y)\,dy^i\otimes dy^j$ for a foliated chart $(x,y)$ and $Q=TM/F\cong F^\perp$).

A principal bundle $P\to(M,F)$ is called foliated, if it is quipped with a lifted foliation $F_P$ invariant under the structure group action, transversal to  the tangent space to the fiber and $TF_P$ projects isomorphically onto $TF$.

For an associated foliated vector bundle $E$, an adapted connection is called **basic**, if the connection $1$-form $\omega$ on its principal bundle $P^E$ satisfies 
  $$L_X\omega=0,$$
   for any $X\in\Gamma(F_p)$.

I have a question about the existence of the basic connection.

**Q**

- Let $E$ be  foliated transversal Clifford bundle 
  that is
  a olaited bundle of $Cl(Q)$-Clifford modules with compatible connection $\nabla^E$. Why it is always
  possible to choose a basic connection for $E$? (from the book, Masayuki Asaoka
  Aziz El Kacimi Alaoui
  Steven Hurder
  Ken Richardson
  , Foliations:
  Dynamics, Geometry
  and Topology, Page 168).
- From the paper,J. Brung, F. W. Kamber, and K. Richardson , INDEX THEORY FOR BASIC DIRAC OPERATORS
  ON RIEMANNIAN FOLIATIONS, authors wrote that:  **basic connections always exist on a foliated principal
  bundle over a Riemannian foliation.** from the book  Foliated Bundles and
  Characteristic Classes. Why it is true?

PS: I think the first problem is from the property that the group of autormphism preserving the foliation is compact. 
For the second problem, I guess the authors mean that the Lie group foliated principal bundle is compact?